# Reverse a word with numbers without affecting spaces, punctuation

Tags: javascript, string, function, reverse, regexp-replace

I'm trying to reverse words with numbers without affecting space and punctuation, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
function reverseWords(str) {
   return str.replace(/[a-z]+/ig, function(w){return w.split('').reverse().join('')}
 );
} 

console.log(reverseWords('Stri_ng;-%   2b$#e reversed'));
```

My expected result is "irtS_gn;-%   b2$#e desrever"

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: test_str = "Stri_ng;-%   2b$#e reversed";     assert(reverse_words(test_str) == "irtS_gn;-%   b2$#e desrever")

Answer (score 0):

Use groups in the regex and the rest of the code remains:

```js
function reverseWords(str) {
  const regex = /([a-z0-9]+)/gi;
  return str.replace(regex, v => v.split('').reverse().join(''))
} 

console.log(reverseWords("Stri_ng;-% 2b$#e reversed"));
```